# What is my Hebrew name verse?

Tags: names

What are the name verses for a name starting with a *tes* ט and ending with a *hey* ה and not the verse from tehilim ( the one in the Artscroll siddur)?

Comment: Name verses? Sorry, I'm not familiar with what you're talking about.

Comment: @rosenjcb: It's already mentioned in the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch (18:15) in the name of the Eliya Raba that it's customary to add a verse after the Amida starting and ending with the same letters as one's name does.

Comment: It originates in something known as [Chibut HaKever](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%97%D7%99%D7%91%D7%95%D7%98_%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%91%D7%A8). (Torments of the grave). It was a belief for a time that after someone died the angel of death would visit the deceased's soul and inquire of them their name. The wicked would forget their name, and endure further punishment while the righteous would remember it. Saying these pesukim became a segulah to remember your name. (See also: [Chabad](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2451435/jewish/Names-Verses-and-Flaming-Hot-Rods.htm))

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure what you have against the verse in the Artscroll. But here are the 9 possibilities:

Breishit 19:4:

> טֶרֶם יִשְׁכָּבוּ וְאַנְשֵׁי הָעִיר אַנְשֵׁי סְדֹם נָסַבּוּ עַל הַבַּיִת מִנַּעַר וְעַד זָקֵן כָּל הָעָם מִקָּצֶה

Breishit 31:39:

> טְרֵפָה, לֹא-הֵבֵאתִי אֵלֶיךָ--אָנֹכִי אֲחַטֶּנָּה, מִיָּדִי תְּבַקְשֶׁנָּה; גְּנֻבְתִי יוֹם, וּגְנֻבְתִי לָיְלָה

Tehilim 140:6

> טָמְנוּ גֵאִים פַּח לִי וַחֲבָלִים פָּרְשׂוּ רֶשֶׁת לְיַד מַעְגָּל מֹקְשִׁים שָׁתוּ לִי סֶלָה

Mishlei 9:2:

> טָבְחָה טִבְחָהּ מָסְכָה יֵינָהּ אַף עָרְכָה שֻׁלְחָנָהּ

Mishlei 19:24

> טָמַן עָצֵל יָדוֹ בַּצַּלָּחַת גַּם אֶל פִּיהוּ לֹא יְשִׁיבֶנָּה

Mishlei 31:18

> טָעֲמָה כִּי טוֹב סַחְרָהּ לֹא יִכְבֶּה בַלַּיְלָה נֵרָהּ

Eicha 2:9

> טָבְעוּ בָאָרֶץ שְׁעָרֶיהָ אִבַּד וְשִׁבַּר בְּרִיחֶיהָ מַלְכָּהּ וְשָׂרֶיהָ בַגּוֹיִם אֵין תּוֹרָה גַּם נְבִיאֶיהָ לֹא מָצְאוּ חָזוֹן מֵי-ה-ו-ה

Eicha 3:26:

> טוֹב וְיָחִיל וְדוּמָם לִתְשׁוּעַת י-ה-ו-ה

Koheles 9:18

> טוֹבָה חָכְמָה מִכְּלֵי קְרָב וְחוֹטֶא אֶחָד יְאַבֵּד טוֹבָה הַרְבֵּה

Comment: Some of those verses are nice, some seem rather inappropriate... I wouldn't say the one referring to the people of Sedom (1), Yaakov's reply to Lavan's trickery (2), describing your enemies (3), describing the Yetzer Hara/Harlot (4), or the lazy person (5), nor the description of the destruction of Jerusalem (7). The one referring to the woman of valor is nice (6), as is the second verse from Eicha about hoping to G-d (8), and the one about wisdom (9) might all be good choices..

Comment: @LN6595 - Yes but the OP asked for all the passukim one could find. So it doesn't matter whether some seem like you wouldn't want to say for your name or not.

Comment: @LN6595 The fourth one isn't describing the yetzer hara/harlot, but just the opposite - Wisdom (Torah) personified. (Only later in the perek does it start describing her opposite number, the "woman of foolishness.")