# What is the hebrew name verse for the name טלי (Tali)

Tags: tefilla, hebrew, names

What is the hebrew name verse for the name טלי (Tali), there isn't one in the artscroll

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Complete list of verses corresponding to people's names](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29629/complete-list-of-verses-corresponding-to-peoples-names?rq=1)

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Avital. I guess Tali wants to recite the verse after the Amidah

Comment: the [link](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00720.html)
result:[תהילים פרק-סט-ג]  טָבַעְתִּי בִּיוֵן מְצוּלָה וְאֵין מָעֳמָד בָּאתִי בְמַעֲמַקֵּי מַיִם וְשִׁבֹּלֶת שְׁטָפָתְנִי: 

[תהילים פרק-קיט-סו]  טוּב טַעַם וָדַעַת לַמְּדֵנִי כִּי בְמִצְוֹתֶיךָ הֶאֱמָנְתִּי: 

[תהילים פרק-קיט-סז]  טֶרֶם אֶעֱנֶה אֲנִי שֹׁגֵג וְעַתָּה אִמְרָתְךָ שָׁמָרְתִּי: 

[תהילים פרק-קיט-ע]  טָפַשׁ כַּחֵלֶב לִבָּם אֲנִי תּוֹרָתְךָ שִׁעֲשָׁעְתִּי: 

[איכה פרק-ד-ט]  טוֹבִים הָיוּ חַלְלֵי חֶרֶב מֵחַלְלֵי רָעָב שֶׁהֵם יָזוּבוּ מְדֻקָּרִים מִתְּנוּבֹת שָׂדָי:

Comment: Strongly recommend  טוּב טַעַם וָדַעַת לַמְּדֵנִי כִּי בְמִצְוֹתֶיךָ הֶאֱמָנְתִּי . The others aren't nearly as nice-sounding. *"Better those who died of the sword than the slow and painful process of starvation"?* Pass.

Comment: When I read this I heard Shoffar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is my Hebrew name verse?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/38062/what-is-my-hebrew-name-verse)

Answer (score 3):

Tehillim (Psalms) 119:66
In Hebrew, this begins with the letter tet and ends with the letter yud.
English translation from Artscroll Stone Chumash of the verse is: "Teach me good reasoning and knowledge, for I have been faithful to Your commandments."

Answer (score 0):

Although you are asking for a Hebrew verse for the name Tali, it seems that is only your nickname, and that your correct Hebrew name is Avital. Thus you need a verse that begins with a Aleph and ends with a Lamed. [Here](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/66650) are 5 choices from הרב יאיר וסרטיל that you can use for the name Avital.

> 1. דברים פרק ב פסוק כז אֶעְבְּרָה בְאַרְצֶךָ בַּדֶּרֶךְ בַּדֶּרֶךְ אֵלֵךְ לֹא אָסוּר יָמִין וּשְׂמֹאול:
> 2. דברים פרק כט פסוק ט אַתֶּם נִצָּבִים הַיּוֹם כֻּלְּכֶם לִפְנֵי ה' אֱלֹהֵיכֶם רָאשֵׁיכֶם שִׁבְטֵיכֶם זִקְנֵיכֶם וְשֹׁטְרֵיכֶם כֹּל אִישׁ
>      יִשְׂרָאֵל:
> 3. ישעיהו פרק מא פסוק יד אַל תִּירְאִי תּוֹלַעַת יַעֲקֹב מְתֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל אֲנִי עֲזַרְתִּיךְ נְאֻם ה' וְגֹאֲלֵךְ קְדוֹשׁ יִשְׂרָאֵל:
> 4. תהלים פרק סט פסוק ז אַל יֵבֹשׁוּ בִי קֹוֶיךָ אֲ-דֹנָי ה' צְבָאוֹת אַל יִכָּלְמוּ בִי מְבַקְשֶׁיךָ אֱלֹהֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל:
> 5. תהלים פרק קמד פסוק יב אֲשֶׁר בָּנֵינוּ כִּנְטִעִים מְגֻדָּלִים בִּנְעוּרֵיהֶם בְּנוֹתֵינוּ כְזָוִיֹּת מְחֻטָּבוֹת תַּבְנִית הֵיכָל:

Comment: Good thinking, but it could also be _Metal_ or _R'vital_ or _Ortal_ or _Tal_ or _Talya_ -- all of which are used in Israel today -- or indeed _Tali_.

Comment: @msh210 The OP's username is "Avital". We don't know anything about her or whom she's asking for, of course.

Comment: @DoubleAA, oh, I hadn't noticed.